# Error during login Python

Tags: python-3.x

I get the error

```
print("You are logged in as: " + user[2])
```

**IndexError: list index out of range**

**why??**

my code is

```
users = open("users.txt").read().split("\n")
for i in range(len(users)): users[i] = users[i].split("|")


while True:
    username = str(input("Username: "))
    password = str(input("Password: "))

    for user in users:
        uname = user[0]
        pword = user[1]

        if uname == username and pword == password:
            print("Hello " + user[1] + ".")
            #print("You are logged in as: " + user[1])
            main_menu()

    # If none of the records matched the input
    print("Wrong username/password.")
    print("Try again!\n\n")
```

and users.txt looks like

```
admin|admin

john|john2
```

Comment: The first line does not occur in your code! Can you edit the code so that it actually fails?

Answer (score 0):

Calling split on every line results in a list with 2 elements:

```
>>> x = 'admin|passw'.split('|')
>>> x
['admin', 'passw']
```

The first element has the index `0`, the second the index `1`. There is no element with index `2`. Observe:

```
>>> x[0]
'admin'
>>> x[1]
'passw'
>>> x[2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Sorry the error i get from the above code is     pword = user[1]
IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0):

The file users.txt has an empty line in your question.

Running your code below with added print().

```
users = open("users.txt").read().split("\n")
for i in range(len(users)): users[i] = users[i].split("|")
print(users)
```

outputs:

```
[['admin', 'admin'], [''], ['john', 'john2'], ['']]
```

Index 1 and 3 have only one item and may cause the error of being out of range. This is the empty line of `\n` and the last line ending with `\n` creating index 1 and 3.

I suggest this code as replacement:

```
users = []
with open("users.txt") as r:
    for line in r:
        # Skip empty line.
        if line == '\n':
            continue
        # Remove whitespace i.e. \n.
        line = line.strip()
        # Append user,password list to the users list.
        if '|' in line:
            users.append(line.split('|'))
print(users)
```

This outputs:

```
[['admin', 'admin'], ['john', 'john2']]
```